# Adding a table row line on Smarty XML template

Tags: php, xml, smarty

I'm working on a [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) XML template and I want to add a line after each table row. CSS styles don't work on XML template. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE menu [
<!ENTITY lt     "&#38;#60;"> 
<!ENTITY gt     "&#62;"> 
<!ENTITY amp    "&#38;#38;"> 
<!ENTITY apos   "&#39;"> 
<!ENTITY quot   "&#34;"> 
]>
<report>
<orientation>landscape</orientation>
<body>
    <p fontsize="+5" fontstyle="bold">{$account}</p>
    <p fontsize="+3">Report</p>
    <p></p>
    <p fontsize="+5" fontstyle="bold">{$title}</p>
    <p fontsize="+2">{$date}</p>
    <p></p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            {foreach from=$columns item=column}
            <th fontstyle="bold">{$column}</th>
            {/foreach}
        </tr>
        {foreach from=$rows item=row}
        <tr>
            {foreach from=$columns item=column key=col_index}
            <td>{if isset($row[$col_index])}{$row[$col_index]}
    {else}              {/if}   </td>
            {/foreach}
        </tr>
        {/foreach}
    </table>
</body>
    </report>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes that's because CSS build for HTML, to use style sheets for XML you need to read a little about XSL